# How to change int interval settings on flutter onchangedlocation.listen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm streaming my location to firestore, but I'd like it to send at a slower rate.  Currently it seems to update every  5000 milliseconds but I cannot figure out how to change it to something more like 50000 milliseconds. How do I modify my code so that it changes the rate at which the locations are streamed? Full github project [here](https://github.com/giroprotagonist/tracker). Thanks for reading.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:tracker/widget/enable_in_background.dart';

class AddLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  final double lat;
  final double lng;
  final double speed;
  AddLocation({Key key, this.lat, this.lng, this.speed}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AddLocationState createState() => _AddLocationState();
}

class _AddLocationState extends State<AddLocation> {
  // Field
  double lat, lng;
  double speed;
  String dateString;

  // Method
  initState(){ Location location = new Location();
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((res) {
      setState(() {
      lat = res.latitude;
      lng = res.longitude;
      });
    insertDataToFirestore();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 42),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: const Text('Post User Location'),
                onPressed: insertDataToFirestore,
              ),
            ),
            EnableInBackgroundWidget()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Stream<Null>> insertDataToFirestore() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await auth.currentUser();
    String email = firebaseUser.email;
    String uid = firebaseUser.uid;
    String displayName = firebaseUser.displayName;
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    String dateString = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy - kk:mm').format(dateTime);

    Map<String, dynamic> map = Map();
    map['DateTime'] = dateString;
    map['Lat'] = lat;
    map['Lng'] = lng;
    map['Speed'] = speed;
    map['Email'] = email;
    map['Uid'] = uid;
    map['DisplayName'] = displayName;

    Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
    firestore.collection('locations');
    await collectionReference.document().setData(map).then((value) {
      print('Upload Success');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using stream, you can do this with workmanager and future
https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

this package sets an interval and you can update firebase entries on this interval with using future.

make your main method like that

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Workmanager.initialize(
    callbackDispatcher,
    isInDebugMode: false,
  ); 
  await Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
    "5", "simplePeriodicTask",
    existingWorkPolicy: ExistingWorkPolicy.replace,
    initialDelay: Duration(seconds: 5),
    constraints: Constraints(
      networkType: NetworkType.connected,
    ),
   frequency: Duration(minutes: 30), // 30 min interval(minimum 15 min)
  );
  runApp(myApp());
}
```

and your method like that

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    

**do firebase update here** 

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds like a great idea, is there any code example you could provide? I am new to programming and flutter so the learning is slow, I will continue reading about workmanager and futures.

Comment: @giroprotagonist i updated my answer check it out. Maybe will help you

Comment: Thanks this code got me going in the right direction, greatly appreciated.